# location of DTSX package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to know the location of a DTSX package which is stored in "file system",

It is visible under Stored pacakges-->filesystem-->Package1 in Integration services .

I tried to do a windows search using "Package1.dtsx" string, But the results lists 5 packages with the same name, How do i know which is the package listed in integration services?. Is there any table i can query to get this info?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740735/where-are-ssis-packages-saved

Comment: Thanks, But this doesn't answer my question. I want to know the "file location" of this package.

Answer (score 3):

On your server, there is a file named MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml which is located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn (for sql server 2014). When I examined this file it stated "..\packages" for the location, so I went to the DTS folder then into the packages folder and the files were there.

Depending on your version, architecture, and installation path) of SQL Server, you might find these files at

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml (2005)
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml (2008/2008R2)
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml (2012)
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml (2014)
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml (2016)

Comment: I believe the location you are referring to is the SSIS package store which defaults to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\packages folder. What if the package is stored in a location  like "D:\data\sqlserver" and i need to find it some how. i need these details for some audit purposes

Comment: If there are multiple packages with the same name, the one that is being executed is the one that the configuration file points to.